# Android delete button

Tags: android, database, sqlite, scrollview, tableview

So I have an activity which has Table View inside a Scroll View.
I dynamically add rows to the table view. Each row  has 2 stings and 2 integers queried from a database. I need to add a button on the row that deletes the entire row , and also delete the data from the database containing that row.

I Have set up the button , but I failed to write onClickListner to it. I do not know how to detect which of the buttons is to be pressed, and how to associate it with the corresponding row.

Any help greatly appreciated. Thanks !

This is the method which adds a row. Location object just holds the data fetched from the DB.

```
    public void insertRow(Location l,int index){
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);


        View newRow = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);

        TextView textview = (TextView) newRow.findViewById(R.id.textViewLocation);
        TextView textview2= (TextView) newRow.findViewById(R.id.coordinates);

        textview2.setText(l.getLatitude() +" | "+ l.getLongitude());
        textview.setText(l.getName());

        //Button remove = (Button) newRow.findViewById(R.id.removeButtonLocation);
        //  remove.setOnClickListener(removeLocationListener);



        // Add the new components for the location  to the TableLayout
        a.addView(newRow, index);


}
```

And the layout file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/locations_textview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/row0"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

    <ScrollView 
        android:id="@+id/Locations_scroll_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        <TableLayout 
            android:id="@+id/stockTableScrollView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/egg_shell" >

        </TableLayout>

    </ScrollView>



    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You will get more help if you include some code on what you have tried.  Please do so, it will also make it clearer what you are trying to do :)

Comment: I have an activity too, he is at home now. Please post some code dude.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so let's start with your issues one at a time. You actually have the code there already, but it is commented out, let's look at it:

```
    Button remove = (Button) newRow.findViewById(R.id.removeButtonLocation);
    remove.setOnClickListener(removeLocationListener);
```

This says there is an object called `removeLocationListener` you haven't included that does the work. An OnClickListener defines just one function, `onClick (View v)`. The View passed is the view in reference. So, you want to get the row associated with that view, and delete it. Let's first get the row:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    TableRow row=(TableRow) v.getParent();
}
```

Okay, so how do you remove the row now that you have it? It turns out you have to remove it from the layout above it. So let's do the same thing done before to get the view it's in:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    TableRow row=(TableRow) v.getParent();
    TableLayout tl=(TableLayout) v.getParent();
    tl.removeView(row);
}
```

Let's just define removeLocationListener somewhere:

```
OnClickListener removeLocationListener= new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        TableRow row=(TableRow) v.getParent();
        TableLayout tl=(TableLayout) v.getParent();
        tl.removeView(row);
    }
};
```

BTW, you might want to look at a [ListView](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html), which is better suited for such things. You can even pass in a Cursor directly to it, which will make the whole thing a lot easier to manage.